# Using @Parcelize but by removing Getters and Setters in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

I'm trying to neglecting getter and setter in kotlin using @Parcelize. But little bit confused, here.

```
class College : Parcelable {
var studentFound = true
    set(value) {
        field = value
        studentFoundEvents.onNext(value)
    }
val studentFoundEvents = PublishSubject.create<Boolean>()

var sNumber: String? = null
var sLevel: String? = null

var course: Course? = null
    set(value) {
        field = value
        cName = null
        cId = null
        cProf = null  
    }
}
```

and i have respective **constructor(source: Parcel) {}**, **override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {}** and  **override fun describeContents(): Int = hashCode()**.

I want to do convert whole Parcelable to @Parcelize.
Here is what i tried, but did not workout.

```
@Parcelize
data class College(
    var studentFound = true,
    val studentFoundEvents = PublishSubject.create<Boolean>(), // does not work here
    var sNumber: String? = null,
    var sLevel: String? = null,
    var course: Course? = null
) : Parcelable
```

Is there is anything missing here? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1):

I figure out couple of hour research about @Parcelize, Don't know this is best approach or not. Always highly recommend anyone, if you have any best solution.

```
@Parcelize
class College : Parcelable {
var studentFound = true
    set(value) {
        field = value
        studentFoundEvents.onNext(value)
    }
val studentFoundEvents = PublishSubject.create<Boolean>()

var sNumber: String? = null
var sLevel: String? = null

var course: Course? = null
    set(value) {
        field = value
        cName = null
        cId = null
        cProf = null  
    }
}
```

Adding ***@Parcelize*** but not moving properties to the constructor and by removing theses

```
constructor(source: Parcel) {}, 
override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {} and 
override fun describeContents(): Int = hashCode().
```

Hope this will help anyone and best approaches are welcome too.

Comment: this gives the warning: Property would not be serialized into a 'Parcel'. Add '@IgnoredOnParcel' annotation to remove the warning. So it doesn't work.